# Installed KDE, now GNOME has kde default cursor

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, gnome, kde

I installed KDE over my Ubuntu 10.04 installation. Now when I log into GNOME I get the KDE default cursor instead of the usual one. It's a minor issue but one I'd like to deal with especially since I'll probably learn something in the process.

KDE works fine though I've decided I prefer GNOME aesthetically.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much of a way to fix this for sure without a lot of unnecessary work. You could try System > Preferences > appearance and then click customize, then go to pointers tab. you can fool around wit hstuff in there and see if it helps! Best wishes!!

Comment: That works inside application windows but not on anything "owned" by the desktop manager, including the window's frame. I found out that this is a known compiz bug.